# Should not working as expected

Tags: javascript, should.js, assertj

I am new to Should testing. Always used Assert but I'm trying new options.

This simple test is not working and I am curious to understand why.

#### Profile.js

```
class Profile {

    constructor(profile_name,user_name,email,language) {
        this.profile_name = profile_name;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.language = language;
    }

}

module.exports = Profile;
```

#### Profile_test.js

```
let should = require('should');

let Profile = require('../lib/entities/Profile');

describe('Profile', function() {

    describe('#constructor', function() {

        it('should return a Profile object', function() {
            let profile = new Profile('alfa','Alfa da Silva','alfa@beta.com','java');
            let valid = { profile_name: 'alfa', user_name: 'Alfa da Silva', email: 'alfa@beta.com', language: 'java'};
            profile.should.equal(valid);
        });

    });

});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> > Profile
> >        #constructor
> >          1) should return a Profile object
> >
> > 0 passing (62ms)
> >      1 failing
> >
> > 1) Profile
> >           #constructor
> >             should return a Profile object:
> >
> > ```
> >  AssertionError: expected Profile {
> > ```
> >
> > profile_name: 'alfa',
> >      user_name: 'Alfa da Silva',
> >      email: 'alfa@beta.com',
> >      language: 'java'
> >     } to be Object {
> >      profile_name: 'alfa',
> >      user_name: 'Alfa da Silva',
> >      email: 'alfa@beta.com',
> >      language: 'java'
> >     }
> >          + expected - actual
> >
> > ```
> >  at Assertion.fail (node_modules/should/cjs/should.js:275:17)
> >  at Assertion.value (node_modules/should/cjs/should.js:356:19)
> >  at Context.<anonymous> (test/Profile_test.js:12:19)
> > ```

What is wrong here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ***profile.should.match***. Because the prototype of two object is different. You can get information from [here](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js/wiki/Breaking-changes#changes-for-9x).

```
 let should = require('should');

let Profile = require('../lib/entities/Profile');

describe('Profile', function() {

    describe('#constructor', function() {

        it('should return a Profile object', function() {
            let profile = new Profile('alfa','Alfa da Silva','alfa@beta.com','java');
            let valid = { profile_name: 'alfa', user_name: 'Alfa da Silva', email: 'alfa@beta.com', language: 'java'};
            profile.should.match(valid);
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From [should documentation](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-equal)

> should.equal(actual, expected, [message])
>
> Node.js standard assert.equal.

And from [Nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_equal_actual_expected_message) we know that assert.equal(...)

> Tests shallow, coercive equality between the actual and expected parameters using the Abstract Equality Comparison ( == ).

Looks like you need to use `eql(..)` or `deepEqual(..)`. Something like

```
profile.should.be.eql(valid);
```